# How many memory barriers instructions does an x86 CPU have?

Tags: multithreading, assembly, x86, memory-barriers

I have found out that an x86 CPU have the following memory barriers instructions: `mfence`, `lfence`, and `sfence`.

Does an x86 CPU only have these three memory barriers instructions, or are there more?

Comment: https://xem.github.io/minix86/manual/intel-x86-and-64-manual-vol3/o_fe12b1e2a880e0ce-273.html (tl;dr: these should be the only memory barriers proper, but there are also several *serializing instructions*)

Comment: Consider upvoting [https://stackoverflow.com/tags/memory-barriers/synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/memory-barriers/synonyms).

Comment: @HadiBrais: There's also a [tag:memory-order], which I also proposed as a synonym.  Although ordering can happen without barriers, it's a really obscure tag.  It's highly related, so maybe belongs together on SO.

Answer (score 13):

**`sfence` (SSE1)  and `mfence` / `lfence` (SSE2) are the only instructions that are named for their memory fence/barrier functionality**.  Unless you're using NT stores and/or WC memory (and NT loads from WC), only `mfence` is needed for memory ordering.

(Note that [`lfence`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/LFENCE.html) on Intel CPUs is also a barrier for out-of-order execution, so it can serialize `rdtsc`, and is useful for Spectre mitigation to prevent speculative execution.  On AMD, there's an MSR that has to be set, otherwise `lfence` is basically a `nop` (4/cycle throughput).  That MSR was introduced with Spectre-mitigation microcode updates, and is normally set by updated kernels.)

---

**`lock`ed instructions like `lock add [mem], eax` are also full memory barriers**.  [Does lock xchg have the same behavior as mfence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40409297/does-lock-xchg-have-the-same-behavior-as-mfence).  (Although possibly not as strong as `mfence` for ordering NT loads from WC memory: [Do locked instructions provide a barrier between weakly-ordered accesses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50280857/do-locked-instructions-provide-a-barrier-between-weakly-ordered-accesses)).  `xchg [mem], reg` has an implicit `lock` prefix, so it's also a barrier.

[In my testing on Skylake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40409297/does-lock-xchg-have-the-same-behavior-as-mfence#comment87582997_50279772), `lock`ed instructions do block reordering of NT stores with regular stores with this code https://godbolt.org/g/7Q9xgz.

`xchg` seems to be a good way to do a seq-cst store, especially on Intel hardware like **Skylake where `mfence` also blocks out-of-order execution of pure ALU instructions**, like `lfence`: See [the bottom of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50494658/are-loads-and-stores-the-only-instructions-that-gets-reordered/50496379#50496379).

AMD also recommends using `xchg` or other locked instructions instead of `mfence`.  (`mfence` is documented in the AMD manuals as serializing on AMD, so it will always have the penalty of blocking OoO exec).

---

For sequential-consistency stores or full barriers on 32-bit targets without SSE, compilers typically use **`lock or [esp], 0`** or other no-op locked instruction *just* for the memory-barrier effect.  [That's what `g++7.3 -O3 -m32 -mno-sse` does](https://godbolt.org/g/EeEN8a) for     `std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_seq_cst);`.

**But anyway, neither `mfence` nor `lock`ed insns are *architecturally* defined as serializing on Intel,** regardless of implementation details on some CPUs.

---

**Full serializing instructions like `cpuid` are also full memory barriers**, draining the store buffer as well as flushing the pipeline.  [Does lock xchg have the same behavior as mfence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40409297/does-lock-xchg-have-the-same-behavior-as-mfence) has relevant quotes from Intel's manual.

On Intel processors, the following are architecturally serializing instructions (From: https://xem.github.io/minix86/manual/intel-x86-and-64-manual-vol3/o_fe12b1e2a880e0ce-273.html):

- **Privileged serializing instructions** — INVD, INVEPT, INVLPG, INVVPID, LGDT, LIDT, LLDT, LTR, MOV to control register, MOV (to debug register), WBINVD, and WRMSR.

  Exceptions: `MOV CR8` isn't serializing.  `WRMSR` to the IA32_TSC_DEADLINE MSR (MSR index 6E0H) and the X2APIC MSRs (MSR indices 802H to 83FH) are not serializing.
- **Non-privileged serializing instructions** — CPUID, IRET<sup>1</sup>, and RSM

On AMD processors, the following are architecturally serializing instructions:

- **Privileged serializing instructions** — INVD, INVLPG, LGDT, LIDT, LLDT, LTR, MOV to control register, MOV (to debug register), WBINVD, WRMSR, and SWAPGS.
- **Non-privileged serializing instructions** — MFENCE, CPUID, IRET, and RSM

The term "[fully] serializing instruction" on Intel processors means the same exact thing as on AMD processors except for one difference: a cache line flushing operation from `CLFLUSH` (but not `CLFLUSHOPT`) is ordered with respect to later instructions by only `MFENCE` on AMD processors.

---

`in` / [`out`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/OUT.html) (and their string-copy versions `ins` and [`outs`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/OUTS:OUTSB:OUTSW:OUTSD.html)) are full memory barriers, and also partially serializing (like `lfence`).  The docs say they delay execution of the next instruction until after "the data phase" of the I/O transaction.

---

Footnotes:

(1) According to BJ137 (Sandy Bridge), HSD152 (Haswell), BDM103 (Broadwell):

> Problem: An IRET instruction that results in a task switch by
> returning from a nested task does not serialize the processor
> (contrary to the Software Developer’s Manual Vol. 3 section titled
> "Serializing Instructions").
>
> Implication: Software  which  depends  on  the  serialization
> property  of  IRET  during  task  switching may  not  behave  as
> expected.  Intel  has  not  observed  this  erratum  to  impact  the
> operation of any commercially available software.
>
> Workaround: None identified. Software can execute an MFENCE
> instruction immediately prior to the IRET instruction if serialization
> is needed.

Comment: The `in` and `out` instructions are also full memory barriers like `mfence` and have serializing properties like `lfence`.

Comment: @HadiBrais: oh, they're not as strongly serializing as `cpuid` or `iret`?  I wasn't trying to enumerate all the serializing instructions, just the different categories.  This HTML snippet of the Intel's vol3 manual (which came up in a google search) lists the fully serializing instructions, for future reference:  https://xem.github.io/minix86/manual/intel-x86-and-64-manual-vol3/o_fe12b1e2a880e0ce-273.html, and you're right, it doesn't list `in` or `out` as serialized, but they are ordered by other instructions.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, the only three memory barrier functions on the x86 CPU are:

```
LFENCE

SFENCE

MFENCE
```

Comment: This answer isn't really nuanced enough: those are the only _dedicated purpose_ fence instructions, but other instructions such as instructions with the `lock` prefix also act as a fence (they act as `mfence`, the strongest of the above fences). So to get the memory barrier effect you don't need one of the above instructions.