# How does "XORL AX, AX" work as a memory fence?

Tags: multithreading, go, assembly, parallel-processing, x86

Recently I've been browsing through Go's source code and in particular [runtime/internal/atomic/asm_386.s](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/runtime/internal/atomic/asm_386.s#L201).
Below is an implementation of an `internal.atomic.Store64` function.

```
// void runtime∕internal∕atomic·Store64(uint64 volatile* addr, uint64 v);
TEXT runtime∕internal∕atomic·Store64(SB), NOSPLIT, $0-12
    MOVL    ptr+0(FP), AX
    TESTL   $7, AX
    JZ  2(PC)
    MOVL    0, AX // crash with nil ptr deref
    // MOVQ and EMMS were introduced on the Pentium MMX.
    MOVQ    val+4(FP), M0
    MOVQ    M0, (AX)
    EMMS
    // This is essentially a no-op, but it provides required memory fencing.
    // It can be replaced with MFENCE, but MFENCE was introduced only on the Pentium4 (SSE2).
    XORL    AX, AX
    LOCK
    XADDL   AX, (SP)
    RET
```

The question is related to the second comment in the function. Could someone explain how does `XORL AX, AX` work as a memory fence?

I guess it has something to do with the `LOCK` that goes right after, but how does it work?

Thank you.

Comment: That's dumb, normal people use `lock addl $0, (SP)` as a (sometimes faster) equivalent for MFENCE.  The other inefficiency is using `testl` instead of `testb` to check the low bits of EAX: there is no `test r32, imm8` encoding so it wastes several bytes of code size.

Comment: Also, I would have used `fild` / `fistp` instead of needing MMX EMMS, if I needed to avoid SSE2.  Or SSE1 movlps load/store into xmm0, although that has a false dependency vs. an SSE2 `movq` or `movsd` load into xmm0.  And I would have put the crash-on-misalignment load after the `ret` so the branch is not-taken in the normal case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn’t the **`XOR`** that acts as a memory fence. It is the locked **`XADD`** instruction that does that. The `XOR` instruction clears **`EAX`** so that the `XADD` instruction doesn’t actually change the contents of memory.

The memory-ordering behavior of locked instructions is described in the answer to this question: [How many memory barriers instructions does an x86 CPU have?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50323347/how-many-memory-barriers-instructions-does-an-x86-cpu-have)